# cisco business dashboard probe scanning outside of given range

Tags: cisco, cisco-small-business

we're deploying Cisco business dashboard with dedicated probe server in our LAN.
I've managed to make everything work, but one thing bothers me.

I configured the probe managed network to only discover devices in given range for example: 192.1.1.100-192.1.1.150, but Dashboard behaves in a way, that it searches for devices outside the range anyway, then deletes for being outside the range, discovers them,deletes them and does this in a loop.
Did I overlook some setting or is it just another Business dashboard "thing" ?
Thanks